# Can't show in resourses/lang/en forlder in Laravel project

Tags: php, html, laravel, backend, laravel-9

I do make a new project on Laravel but I Can't show it in the resources/lang/en folder in the Laravel project.

I show it in the folder just resources/CSS, Js & Views not but I want resources/Lang, CSS, Js & Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Laravel 9, the `lang` directory has been moved to the root project directory.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#the-lang-directory

Comment: oh that's great I. found the directory